# Create shortcut for interactive compile command

Tags: customize, comint, compile

I know that we can start `compile` interactively using `C-u M-x compile`. Is there a way to start this whenever I run `M-x compile`? If that cannot be done, how do I create a shortcut to `C-u M-x compile`?

My current shortcut for `M-x compile` is:

`(global-set-key (kbd "<f5>") 'compile)`

This would execute normal compile (not interactive). Ideally, I would like to create a separate shortcut for interactive compile (for program that requires a lot of user inputs).

Please let me know and thanks for your help

**Edit:**  I forgot the mention that my compile command is also customized based on mode hook.  For example, below is how I customize it for C++ mode hook and Fortran mode hook:

```
(add-hook 'c++-mode-hook
        (lambda ()
        (set (make-local-variable 'compile-command)
            (concat "g++ -g -Wall -lm " buffer-file-name " && ./a.out"  ) )))




(add-hook 'fortran-mode-hook
        (lambda ()
        (set (make-local-variable 'compile-command)
            (concat "gfortran " buffer-file-name " && ./a.out"  ) )))
```

Comment: @lawlist: I  tried your answer, and it only shows a compilation window with the output from `ls -la`.  This compilation window is not in comint mode, because if I do `C-u M-x compile`, then the compilation window would have something like "Comint mode started at....".  I also customize my compile command base on mode-hook, will update that in the question asap.

Comment: Sorry, I deleted the original comment shortly before you responded.  How about?  `(global-set-key [f5] (lambda () (interactive) (let ((current-prefix-arg '(4))) (call-interactively 'compile))))`  I see that the function `call-interactively` has optional arguments, one of them being KEYS -- it may be possible to use that argument as an alternative to setting the `current-prefix-arg` as I have done in the example of this comment.

Comment: @lawlist: that works, thank you so much! And it also respects my customized mode hook

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```lisp
(global-set-key [f5] (lambda ()
                       (interactive)
                       (let ((current-prefix-arg '(4)))
                         (call-interactively 'compile))))
```